# How to open a Xamarin Forms page from a Xamarin Droid Activity from a onclick listener

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am working on adding an assist feature to my app that when the user holds down on the home button an android activity opens with cards that the user can click on that then opens the xamarin forms page in question for example when the math card is clicked the MathPage xamarin forms page opens here's my android layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_tools_home_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/whole"
        tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/one"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardsbg"
                app:cardElevation="3dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                tools:layout_conversion_absoluteX="16dp"
                tools:layout_conversion_absoluteY="8dp"
                tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="379dp"
                tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="540dp">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/webcard"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/card_background"
                        app:cardElevation="3dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:onClick="web">
                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">
                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/webicon"
                                android:layout_width="68dp"
                                android:layout_height="68dp"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/web" />
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/web"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/webicon"
                                android:text="Internet"
                                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/cardText"
                                android:textSize="20sp" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/mailcard"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/webcard"
                        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/card_background"
                        app:cardElevation="3dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:onClick="email">
                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">
                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/emailicon"
                                android:layout_width="68dp"
                                android:layout_height="68dp"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/email" />
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/email"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/emailicon"
                                android:text="Email"
                                android:textColor="@color/cardText"
                                android:textSize="20sp" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/mathcard"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/mailcard"
                        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/card_background"
                        app:cardElevation="3dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:onClick="math">
                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">
                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/musicicon"
                                android:layout_width="68dp"
                                android:layout_height="68dp"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/math" />
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/music"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/musicicon"
                                android:text="Math"
                                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/cardText"
                                android:textSize="20sp" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/scicard"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/mathcard"
                        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/card_background"
                        app:cardElevation="3dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:onClick="science">
                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">
                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/playicon"
                                android:layout_width="68dp"
                                android:layout_height="68dp"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:padding="8dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/sci" />
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/play"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playicon"
                                android:text="Science"
                                android:textColor="@color/cardText"
                                android:textSize="20sp" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/englishcard"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/scicard"
                        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/card_background"
                        app:cardElevation="3dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:onClick="english">
                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">
                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/playicon"
                                android:layout_width="68dp"
                                android:layout_height="68dp"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:padding="8dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/handwrittin" />
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/play"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playicon"
                                android:text="Handwriting"
                                android:textColor="@color/cardText"
                                android:textSize="20sp" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/flashcard"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/englishcard"
                        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/card_background"
                        app:cardElevation="3dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:onClick="flashcard">
                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">
                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/playicon"
                                android:layout_width="68dp"
                                android:layout_height="68dp"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:padding="8dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/flashcards" />
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/play"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playicon"
                                android:text="Flashcards"
                                android:textColor="@color/cardText"
                                android:textSize="20sp" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/bttom"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/flashcard"
                        android:paddingTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_2"
                            android:onClick="cam"
                            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/settings" />
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button_1"
                            android:onClick="settings"
                            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/settings" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:id="@+id/button_4"
            android:onClick="now"
            android:layout_marginTop="-42dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/scroll"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/books" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

heres my code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

namespace AppName.Droid
{
[Activity(LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleInstance, Theme = "@style/Theme.Transparent")]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionAssist }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault })]    
    public class ToolBelt : FormsApplicationActivity
    {

        Button mathbutton;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ToolBelt);

        }


        //Code That Opens The Math  Part!

        [Java.Interop.Export("math")] // The value found in android:onClick attribute.
        public void btnOneClick4(View v) // Does not need to match value in above attribute.
        {

            //code to open the MathPage Forms Page Goes here
        }

        //Code That Opens The Internet  App!

        [Java.Interop.Export("web")] // The value found in android:onClick attribute.
        public void btnOneClick8(View v) // Does not need to match value in above attribute.
        {
            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("http://www.google.com");
            var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
            StartActivity(intent);
        }



        //Code That Opens The Gmail App!

        [Java.Interop.Export("email")] // The value found in android:onClick attribute.
        public void btnOneClick3(View v) // Does not need to match value in above attribute.
        {
            var intent = PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.gm");
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You would need to launch the MainLauncher Activity (the one that inits `Xamarin.Forms`) with some Intent extras, then pass those extras into the Form's Application and open the appropriate Form-based Page based upon that info.

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks for the reply! can you please provide me a link or some example code  on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example...

#### A NON-Form's based Page Selection `Activity`:

User taps a button and we create an `Intent` to open the main Forms' based `Activity` and add a string `Extra` with the "page" that that user selected.

```
[Activity(Label = "PageSelectionActivity", Theme = "@style/MyTheme",  Name = "com.sushhangover.openpage.PageSelectionActivity")]
public class PageSelectionActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.PageSelection);
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);
        button.Click += delegate 
        {
            var intent = new Intent(ApplicationContext, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.PutExtra("page", "StackOverflowPage");
            StartActivity(intent);          
        };
    }
}
```

#### Modify your `MainActivity` to obtain the Extra (if any) and pass it to the App .actor:

```
[Activity(Label = "OpenPage.Droid", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MyTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

        var page = Intent.GetStringExtra("page");
        LoadApplication(new App(page));
    }
}
```

#### Modify the App default .actor to accept parameter and act upon it:

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App(string pageName = "SomeDefaultMainApplicationEntryPage")
    {
        switch (pageName)
        {
            case "StackOverflowPage":
                MainPage = new NavigationPage(new StackOverflowPage);
                break;
            default:
                MainPage = new NavigationPage(new SomeDefaultMainApplicationEntryPage);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Testing

You can open the page selection Activity using adb to launch it:

```
adb shell am start -n com.sushhangover.openpage/.PageSelectionActivity
```

**Note:** You will need to handle the `Xamarin.Form` Page life-cycles as it can get messy depending upon if your `ToolBelt` Activity is opened while the user already has your app open and it is in the middle of some activity and you destroy their work by *re-starting* the app....

Comment: thank you so much for the sample I tried your example and have run into a few issues first off when i click the math button it opens the forms part of the app but it opens the main home page not the math page heres a gitlist of the current code based on you example: https://gist.github.com/TeamBrainStorm/aaedf7a44440895960d23052d6de1b32 can you please take  look and let me know what i'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Phoneswapshop It *looks* right, place breakpoint on the line `LoadApplication(new App(page));` what is the value of the page variable? is it "Math"? or null?

Comment: after placing a breakpoint on the LoadApplication(new App(page)); I found that  page variable is null how do I go about fixing that?please let me know and thank you for all the help so far! :)

Comment: @Phoneswapshop That mean an extra can not be found that has the "page" key, Place a breakpoint on the line `intent.PutExtra("page", "Math");` and on the `switch (pageName)` line and trace the results to ensure the page is being passed properly...

Comment: i did as you said and the pageName value is null as well any tips on how to fix this? please let me know :)

Comment: I just did a clean and uninstalled the app from my device and reinstalled and it works now! thank you so much for all your help!!

Comment: i'm starting to see what you meant about the Forms Page life-cycles going wanky any suggestions on how to go about fixing that?